Are there good reason to accept float but not int in a function in Python?
In a big library, I had a 'bug' because a function which accept only float but not int
def foo(penalty: float):
    if not isinstance(penalty, float):
      raise ValueError(f"`penalty` has to be a float, but is {penalty}")
    # some instruction

I would like to open a PR with the following :
def foo(penalty: int | float):
    if not isinstance(penalty, (int,float)):
      raise ValueError(f"`penalty` has to be a float or int, but is {penalty}")
    # some instruction

but before this, I ask myself :
are there good reason, in Python to accept float but not int ?

At least for Python 3.x (2.x had integer division) if the number isn't transferred to a compiled extension module (where such flexible type checking is more work), I see no reason to reject an int.

In the end, this is really about "that library". Nobody here can really tell you what their requirements are. And remember that there is also a complex type ... so regarding your idea, just create the PR and see what happens. Beyond that ... I can't think of a specific reason to do that, but then, people have a lot of ideas. Maybe someone really wants to make sure that only floats come in. Where, well: if so, that would be awkward, and should be explained somewhere in that code.

You should also adjust the type annotation in your PR.

@MichaelButscher yes, good remark.

The library in question is transformers (from hugging face). I didn't want to write it in the question to be general. I will create the PR and see what happen.

Conceivably an int might have different implicit meaning from the calling context, but mostly an int will do for whatever a float will do.

@MichaelButscher It's actually unnecessary. int is already compatible with float.

A few reasons might exist:

Floats have methods that integers don't. For example the fromhex or hex methods exist on float objects, but not int objects. If the function makes use of such methods, accepting an int will cause it to fail.

Sometimes, floats are specifically needed when dealing with foreign functions, for example, a function expecting a C double, a float works for this purpose, but an int does not.

Other types are accepted by isinstance checks of int, for example bool objects, which may be undesirable.

In Python2, arithmetic with integers can sometimes produce different results than when a float is used. If the library is (or was) backwards compatible to Python2, it could be an artifact of that fact

A function may explicitly expect a value that can only be expressed as a float. For example, if a function is expecting a value between (non-inclusive) 0 and 1, an int will never make sense.


Presumably, a function could just upcast the integer to a float as-needed:
if isinstance(arg, int):
    arg = float(arg)

But for performance, it may be better to error out and inform the user a float is needed (so perhaps the user can use a float to begin with).

Thanks for your answer. After a brief look in the code, the library does only basic operation with it (+,/,*) so I guess it safe to accept int also. But your answer is full of ideas that are good to know.
